# How to Auto-call login function after disconnect from SignalGo socket

Tags: c#, websocket, tcpclient, signalgo

I'm using the [SignalGo](https://github.com/SignalGo/SignalGo-full-net) software library for duplex services and The connection between client and server disconnected and I got permission denied error when I'm going to call the server-side functions and I have to call login function in each access denied response.

How to auto-call login function in duplex connection when the client disconnected?

Comment: Use the events from the client: https://github.com/SignalGo/SignalGo-full-net/wiki/Client-Connected-and-Disconnected-events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define Login as priority method (see the code), every time your client disconnects, when SignalGo reconnect again successfully, Login will be executed automatically.
If login success, SignalGo automatically executes the pending method you called:

```
        SignalGo.Client.ClientProvider clientProvider = new SignalGo.Client.ClientProvider();
        clientProvider.AddPriorityFunction(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                //call login method
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return SignalGo.Client.PriorityAction.NoPlan;
        });
```

However AddPriorityFunction has an async function that named AddPriorityAsyncFunction if you want call it async.